# Deriving group velocity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, superposition, phase-velocity

At the introduction to quantum mechanic [phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) $v_p$ and [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) $v_g$ velocities are often presented. I know how to derive $v_p$ and get equation:

$$
\scriptsize
v_p=\frac{\omega}{k}.
$$

What i dont know is how to explain a derivation of a group velocity $v_g$ to myself. Our professor did derive it, but i am having some difficulties with it.

---

1st he did a superposition of 2 waves with the same amplitude $s_0$:

$$
\scriptsize
\begin{split}
s &= s_0 \sin(\omega_1t-k_1x) + s_0 \sin(\omega_2t - k_2 x)\\
s &= s_0 \left[ \sin(\omega_1t-k_1x) + \sin(\omega_2t - k_2 x) \right]\\
s &= 2s_0 \left[ \sin\left(\frac{(\omega_1t-k_1x)+(\omega_2 t -k_2 x)}{2}\right) \cdot \cos\left(\frac{(\omega_1t-k_1x)-(\omega_2t - k_2 x)}{2}\right) \right]\\
s &= 2s_0 \left[ \sin\left(\frac{\omega_1 + \omega_2}{2} t - \frac{k_1 + k_2}{2} x\right) \cdot \cos\left(\frac{\omega_1 - \omega_2}{2} t - \frac{k_1 - k_2}{2} x\right) \right]\\
s &= 2s_0 \left[ \sin\left(\overline \omega t - \overline{k} x\right) \cdot \cos\left(\frac{\Delta \omega}{2} t - \frac{\Delta k}{2} x\right) \right]\\
\end{split}
$$

---

Here $\overline \omega$ is larger than $\Delta \omega$ and this is why:

- $\scriptsize\sin \left(\overline{\omega}t - \overline k x\right)$ is a part which declares an *envelope* and
- $\scriptsize\cos \left(\frac{\Delta{\omega}}{2}t - \frac{\Delta k}{2} x\right)$ is a part which declares *phases inside an envelope*.

[image]

---

Than professor takes only a part which declares an envelopa and says that phase of this part must be **constant** like this:

$$
\scriptsize\frac{\Delta{\omega}}{2}t - \frac{\Delta k}{2} x = const.
$$

**QUESTION:**
What does this mean? Does a constant phase mean to only look at one point which is allways at the same distance from $x$ axis? Please someone explain this a bit.

Well then he derives the group velocity easily from now on like this:

$$
\scriptsize
\begin{split}
\frac{\Delta{\omega}}{2}t - \frac{\Delta k}{2} x &= const.\\
\frac{\Delta k}{2} x &= \frac{\Delta{\omega}}{2}t -  const.\\
x &= \frac{\Delta{\omega}}{ \Delta k} t -  \frac{2}{\Delta k}const.\\
\end{split}
$$

If i partially diferentiate $x$ i finally get group velocity:

$$
\scriptsize
\begin{split}
v_g &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \\
v_g&= \frac{\Delta{\omega}}{ \Delta k}\\
v_g&= \frac{\textrm d{\omega}}{ \textrm d k}
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original formula we have that $$\omega_1t-k_1x = A$$say, and $$\omega_2t-k_2x =  B$$say, by hypothesis for a specific point at time $t$ and position $x$. This is a point of constant phase (for the $A$ wave and $B$ wave respectively.) To determine the velocity of a (sine or cosine) wave from first principles one wants to know the velocity of that point: how far does a point of constant phase move in time t? This gives the answer of the phase velocity

$$
v_p=\frac{\omega}{k}
$$

So the component waves are moving with phase velocities: $v_{p1}$ and $v_{p2}$ respectively. Using the above values for $A$ and $B$ the middle derivation is an application of the trigonometric identity:

$$
sin A + sin B = 2 sin (1/2(A+B)) \cdot cos (1/2(A-B)).
$$

This gives your expression for $s = s(x,t)$. So how can one talk about a point of constant phase here to obtain the group velocity as it is a product of sin and cos?

Well the trick indeed is to recognise the two separate wave components and treat these (for now) as two separate waves and calculate *their* (phase) velocity - ie the rate of movement of points of constant phase in each "wave".

For the sine wave ie the envelope we would get $\frac{\overline{\omega}}{\overline{k}}$.

Now for the cosine wave. The short answer is that we are looking for its phase velocity also, namely $\frac{\Delta{\omega}}{\Delta k}$.

However what your professor has done here, is to calculate from first principles the velocity of that cosine wave. That is to ask for the definition of a point of constant phase, viz: $\frac{\Delta{\omega}}{2}t - \frac{\Delta k}{2} x = const$ and then to determine the velocity (by differentiation, etc) of this point, again resulting in

$$
v_g=\frac{\Delta\omega}{\Delta k}
$$

Comment: But $\omega_1t-k_1x$ isn't constant. $x$ and $t$ are variables of a wave. How did u mean this? Can you explain how this can be a constant?

Comment: I have extended this answer to cover some background to the calculation.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I think i understand now. Group velocity here is a phase velocity of an envelope. NICE TRICK!

Comment: what is a point of constant phase?

Answer (score 2):

Explanation is perfect but there is some mistake in it the part where you said:

Here ω is larger than Δω and this is why:

Correction

sin⁡(ωt−kx) is a part which declares the phase inside the envelope.

AND

Cos⁡(Δω/2t−Δk/2x) is a part which declares the envelope.

The reason being ω > ∆ω (obviously) and more ω less T causing the wave to cramp up. Thus that's where I think you are wrong. Group velocity: is nothing but the phase velocity of an envelope of the above mentioned wave. So the equation of envelope is:

Cos⁡(Δω/2t−Δk/2x)

So here we will consider two points that would be the Crest A & B of the wave. The Crests are in phase ( both point phase= Δω/2t−Δk/2x= π/2)
so we can conclude the phase is  constant in the wave equation. 
If you have problem doing that visualize by this : you could also prove like this
[image: for the explanation of grp velocity]

PS: SORRY FOR CRAPPY HANDWRITING AND DRAWING SKILLS