# Is difference in wave number always small?

Tags: waves, differentiation, dispersion

Over the last few days I have been looking at a derivation of [group velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity). The derivation is the one shown in this question [Deriving group velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52319/deriving-group-velocity). I have seen this derivation in many places, and in all they without comment say do the following.

In the derivation we get

$$v_g=\frac{\Delta \omega}{\Delta k}$$
And letting $\Delta k \rightarrow 0$ we then get:
$$v_g=\frac{d \omega}{d k}$$
They then say that this holds in general. The only way that I can see this to be true is if $\Delta k$ is always small, no matter what wave we use. So is there some ristriction on how large $\Delta k$ can be so that we can always go from my first expression to my second.

If there is no restriction, then I could chose $\Delta k$ to be large my first expression would hold and my second would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group velocity depends on the relationship between $\omega$ and $k$ which is not, in general, constant. Thus, the group velocity will be a function of $\omega$. But for a given value of $\omega$ there is a corresponding value of $k$.

If you permit the initial wave packet to contain a wide range of frequencies, you get a phenomenon called *dispersion* in which different frequencies travel at different velocities, and in general will cause the packet to spread. That makes it more difficult to talk about group velocity - is it the front of the packet, the middle, or the back that you are looking at to determine the velocity?

It's not a rigorous explanation but I hope it helps - as the frequency content increases, group velocity becomes a more poorly defined concept.

Comment: Hi Floris, thanks for your answer. Is what you are saying the following: if we permit a large range of $k$ (so that $\Delta k$ can be large) then the wave packet spreads out at to large a rate to clearly define a group velocity. Thus in situations where we want to find the group velocity, we will usually focus on situations where $\Delta k$ is small?

Comment: That is more or less what I am saying, although not so categorically. I do think that for a wave packet with a wide range of frequencies, dispersion will make group velocity a less well-defined concept, which is why we usually focus on the situation that is easier to analyze and visualize.

Comment: However for the wave $y=cos(\Delta \omega t +\Delta k x)cos(\bar \omega t+\bar k t)$ I cannot see why the wave packet would spread out at any rate?

Comment: The spreading depends on whether the phase velocity is a function of frequency - which it is for most media. Think rainbows...

Comment: Sorry one more thing, we are therefore saying that $\frac{d \omega}{d k}$ is only an approximation?

Comment: When there is dispersion, it is an approximation. When there is no dispersion I think it is accurate.